# Fetch Inner Json of Array using Mongo Cursor

Tags: java, json, mongodb, cursor

Using Cursor need to fetch values of Inner Json which is in Array
Document looks like this

```
{

    "_id" : ObjectId("5772932ce4b0be6213704c81"),
    "employerId" : "57728cd7e4b0be6213704b17",
    "jobSeekerId" : "5706426ae4b0c7ea74fda18b",
    "readByJobSeeker" : true,
    "readByJobEmployer" : true,
    "interestChat" : [
        {
            "userChat" : "is this job avaliable ",
            "lastChatRole" : "JOBSEEKER",
            "lastChatTime" : ISODate("2017-08-10T15:20:25.017Z"),
            "jobSeekerAcknowledgeFlag" : true,
            "connectionCounterIncreamented" : false
        }
    ],
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-06-28T15:09:32.564Z"),
    "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2017-08-10T15:31:12.564Z"),
    "version" : NumberLong(20),
    "active" : true
}
```

Issue is using query

```
db.interest.find({"interestChat":{$exists:true}}).forEach(function(myChat){print ("interest :: "+ myChat.interestChat); } ).pretty()
```

Not able to fetch data from Array as output come out as
 interest :: [object BSON]
Need to fetch values of Inner json

Comment: It's also a `List`. Iterate it `myChat.interestChat.forEach(...`

Answer (score 0):

The function `print` is not meant to bring json/bson objects.

Try `printjson` instead.

```
db.interest.find({"interestChat":{$exists:true}})
    .forEach(function(myChat){
        printjson({"interest": myChat.interestChat});
    })
```

OR just `printjson(myChat.interestChat);`